# Undefined control sequence \tabhead

Tags: tables, undefined, sequence

I am using a Master/Doctoral Thesis from https://www.latextemplates.com.
I have got a very simpel problem which is undefined control sequence \tabhead!
Can anybody help me to overcome that?

I will be very pleased.

Best,
Pouya

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside, english, singlespacing,liststotoc, toctotoc,headsepline,]{MastersDoctoralThesis}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\usepackage{mathpazo} 

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{example.bib}

\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\geometry{
    paper=a4paper,
    inner=2.5cm,
    outer=3.8cm,
    bindingoffset=.5cm, 
    top=1.5cm,
    bottom=1.5cm, 
    %showframe,}

\begin{table}
\caption[Environmental sustainability constraints]{Four set of constraints as environmental sustainability which scale the human economic.}
\label{tab:activities}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{0.2\linewidth}p{0.7\linewidth}}
\toprule
\tabhead{Number} & \tabhead{Activity}\\
\midrule
1 \& 2 & The use of renewable and non-renewable resources on the source side\\
3 \& 4 & Pollution and Waste assimilation on the sink side\\
\bottomrule\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Neither the documentclass you use nor any of the packages you load defines the command `\tabhead` which is why you end up with the error message. What do you expect `\tabhead` to do/result in? Did you read about this command somewhere? If so, where?

Answer (score 2):

From the website that you mention, download and unpack [`thesis_1.zip`](https://www.latextemplates.com/templates/theses/1/thesis_1.zip). In the file `Chapters/Chapter1.tex`, near the top, you will find the following lines:

```
% Define some commands to keep the formatting separated from the content 
\newcommand{\keyword}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\tabhead}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\newcommand{\file}[1]{\texttt{\bfseries#1}}
\newcommand{\option}[1]{\texttt{\itshape#1}}
```

This means: if you want to use the command `\tabhead` in your document, add a line like the one above to your preamble:

```
\documentclass[...]{...}
...
\newcommand{\tabhead}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
...
\begin{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much. You don't know how grateful I am!